# Trouble with recursive flood-fill on 2D list for minesweeper

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, minesweeper

Having trouble figuring out how to create a recursive function that will fill all empty fields and show mine clues on a 2D list game board.  I understand the how the function is supposed to operate but still cannot seem to come to a working solution.

I've been trying to have my function call the recursive call until it finds and integer in the row, then continue to the next row.
I know i should be passing in the board with the mine clues so the recursive call knows when it hits an integer, just unsure how to go about it.

currently this is all I've got;

```
def island(board, row, col):


    if board[row][col] != " ":
        board[row][col] = " "


        if row != 1:
            island(board,row-1,col)

        if row != maxRow:
            island(board,row+1,col)

        if col != maxCol:
            island(board,row,col+1)

        if col != 1:
            island(board,row,col-1)
```

the results from the code posted above will just clear out any the entire board, working as the current code should

Expected results when a field such as row 4, column 2, is played are:

```
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
   # # # # # # # # # #
 1 # . . . . . . . . #
 2 # 1 1 1 1 . . . . #
 3 #       2 . . . . #
 4 #     1 . . . . . #
 5 #     1 . . . . . #
 6 #     1 . . . . . #
 7 #   1 . . . . . . #
 8 # 1 1 . . . . . . #
   ###################
```

actual results when row 4, column 2, is played are;

```
        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
     # # # # # # # # # # 
  1  #                  #
  2  #                  #
  3  #                  #
  4  #                  #
  5  #                  #
  6  #                  #
  7  #                  #
  8  #                  #
     # # # # # # # # # #
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only moving up and left in your flood fill. You need to move down and right also.

```
    if row != max_row: # Look down
        island(board,row+1,col)
    if col != max_col: # Look right
        island(board,row,col+1)
```

Comment: Thank you, made corrections and added that, what I am truly struggling with is setting my base case for when I encounter an integer 1-8. would using a dictionary be beneficial in this instance?

Comment: @Togoneforgood That sounds like a separate question from floodfill

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help, flood is working at intending-- now I've got to figure a solution to only reveal empty fields, opposed to the whole board.

Comment: @Togoneforgood The conditional on the second line of your code

Comment: @Draconics Should i also be passing in the game board with the generated mine clues?